# A proof about Extended transition function of NFA

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata

I want to prove below statement:

> $δ^*(q,wv) = \cup_{p \in δ^*(q,w)} δ^*(p,v)$

However, I'm not exactly sure how to start. Any idea how can i start the proof?

Comment: How do you define $\delta^*$?

Answer (score 0):

What about doing an induction proof based upon the length of the string $wv$? Can we agree that theorem is trivially true if $|wv| = 1$?

Comment: It might be easier to use induction on the length of $v$.